# local report server not showing Content and Property tab

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a serious issue with my report server.

I cannot see the Content,Properties at the Home Page. And if I click on a report, I cannot see the View, Properties, History and Subscriptions tabs.

Below is what I see on the Home page.

Tuesday, November 06, 2012 5:25 PM         Data Sources

Tuesday, November 06, 2012 5:25 PM         Reports
Does someone know how I can get the tabs back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jamie for your response.
I was looking on the wrong side. I was looking in the Report Server, not in the report manager. The report Server is not basically meant to get browsed and if we do, we will not see the tabs that we see in the report manager. 
for those later who might have the same issue, make sure you are using the Report Manager link intead of the Report Server.

Hope it may help some of you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connecting with a server administrator account. If browsing from the local machine, use "Run as Administrator" to launch IE with full privileges.